Li-ion battery cells dying
I have been having a problem with some Li-ion batteries that are 4S1P. We manufacture them and we have found some of the batteries having 1, 2 or 3 cells dead after just a few months after being manufactured.
We receive li-ion cells with 850mAh / 3.6V nominal voltage / 4.20V End-of Change voltage / 2.75V discharge cut-off voltage / 0.2C discharge rate.
We pick 4 of those cells, solder them, put some adhesive, and also connect a protection circuit PCB (BMS). We encapsulate them properly and perform some tests to review their performance (basically testing that they charge, discharge properly, and that the protection circuit cuts when needed). We also have a PTC connected that cuts if the temperature is above 60ºC.
We store them for a few months in a dry environment, with temperatures between 20-30 ºC.
After that, we perform the tests again and we see that some cells have died.
There seems to be no physical damage or leakage.
I don't know what could be causing this problem, any ideas???


Not enough information. Low quality cells, low quality BMS maybe? Or incorrect method of soldering, you don't say what kind of terminals the cell have but they are usually welded.

"solder them" How? Are they spot welded from the manufacturer so that there's a protuding metal piece for soldering?

Also you do store them charged, yes?

Sorry for not providing enought information. The cells may be low quality, they are bought from a chinese manufacturer. I attach a picture of the soldering and the terminals in the original question. @Justme

We store them at 35% of charge @Lundin

they are bought from a chinese manufacturer then maybe you should speak to your far-eastern manufacturer as well.

Ok provided that the welding is done properly (which we don't know) then that looks like what I had in mind. Some might get the idea to solder wires directly onto the cell and that's obviously not a good idea.

Could it be that the cells already have individual protection circuitry? When making own battery with own BMC, the cells should be of unprotected kind.
